# Change an image using a link from an array

Tags: javascript

I think it should be fairly simple but I'm trying to change an image on my website using a link from an array. I can't seem to get it working, though.

The code is :

```
changeTeamImages("http://url.com/image.jpg");

}

function changeTeamImages(image) {
    document.getElementById("home-logo").src = changeImage(image);
}
```

Any ideas as to why this is not working?

edit:

The array would be something like :

```
var imageSource = {url1, url2, url3};
```

Comment: can you show what `changeImage` is?

Comment: what are you returning form `changeTeamImages("http://url.com/image.jpg");

}` function ?

Comment: Nothing, the function is supposed to take the image link and change the image in the html.

Comment: I can't see how you're trying to use the array. You have an image url, and you're passing it to a function. Where does an array of extra urls come into it?

Comment: Exactly now where is the array? if you wants to change the image directly pass it to the `src`. Why are you calling a function?

Answer (score 0):

There is no array in your code above, but you just need to remove the function so you assign the src as:

```
document.getElementById("home-logo").src = image;
```

Comment: Updated the main post.

Comment: I used this and it works. Silly me tried to update the image using the images div id. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
function changeTeamImages(image) {
    document.getElementById("home-logo").src = image;
}
```

or if change Image is an array :

```
changeTeamImages(1); // if the image you want is at position 1

}

function changeTeamImages(arraypos) {
    document.getElementById("home-logo").src = changeImage[arraypos];
}
```